# Visual studio code comment tags for specific filetype like SASS changed

Tags: css, sass, comments, visual-studio-code

So I am at complete loss here and can not figure out what changed but suddenly my IDE visual studio code on mac OS uses different comment tags for my SASS files when using cmd + /.

In the past it uses // to out comment my code but now it changed to css comment tags: /*  */. I really have no clue what changed and why. In the bottom right it still says its a SASS file. Did I change something myself or did something change in visual studio code itself?

Answer (score 0):

In SASS you can comment using either // or /**/.  // is used for single line.  /* */ is used for multiple lines.  Try highlighting multiple lines and pressing ctrl + / vs highlighting a single line.